# Bits target, Increase/Decrease in ease of mine

Tags: hash, mining-reward

I am currently studying Block Chain technology and at this moment studying the contents of blocks.

To my understanding; A block has to be mined every 10 Minutes.

If the Bit Target sees that Blocks are struggling to be mined every 10 minutes will it then decrease/increase the Bit Target?

If the Bit Target sees that Blocks are easily being mined in less than 10 minutes will it then decrease/increase the Bit Target

I know that the nonce is random I believe it starts at 0 and then is appended to the previous merkle root and then hashed and if its below the bit target then success and if its above then it increases the nonce +1 and repeats the process (Basically trial and error)

However the reason I found struggle is because I dont know if decreasing/increasing is making it more difficult/easier since I don't know the number ones its been hashed.

If somebody could answer my two questions and confirm the things I am saying are true/false really would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Decreasing the target makes finding the correct block hash harder because the range of possible values is smaller. There are less numbers for 1 to 10 than there are from 1 to 100. So by making the target smaller, it becomes less likely for the correct hash to be found and thus the difficulty increases.

Increasing the target makes finding the correct block hash easier because the range of possible values is greater. By making the target larger, it becomes more likely for the correct hash to be found and thus the difficulty decreases.

The relationship between difficulty and the target is inverse.